# YAML front matter for Jekyll and nested lists

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I have a set of nested yaml lists with something like the following:

```
title: the example
image: link.jpg
products:
 - top-level: Product One
   arbitrary: Value
   nested-products:
    - nested: Associated Product
      sub-arbitrary: Associated Value
 - top-level: Product Two
   arbitrary: Value
 - top-level: Product Three
   arbitrary: Value
```

I can loop through the products with no problem using `for item in page.products` and I can use a logic operator to determine if nested products exist - what I CAN'T do is loop through multiple `nested-products` per iteration of `top-level`

I have tried using `for subitem in item` and other options - but I can't get it to work - any ideas?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Update

This example I just wrote (called index.html)

```
---
title: the example
products:
 - top-level: Product One
   arbitrary: Value
   nested-products:
    - nested: Associated Product
      sub-arbitrary: Associated Value
    - nested: Another associate
      sub-arbitrary: with its associated value
 - top-level: Product Two
   arbitrary: Value
   nested-products:
    - nested: nested product Two
      sub-arbitrary: Two's nested's associate value
 - top-level: Product Three
   arbitrary: Value
 - top-level: Product Four
   arbitrary: SomeValue
---
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>

<body>

<h4>products:</h4>
<ul>{% for product in page.products %}
  <li>{{ product.top-level }}: {{ product.arbitrary }}{% if product.nested-products %}
    <ul>
    {% for nestedproduct in product.nested-products %}  <li>{{ nestedproduct.nested }}: {{ nestedproduct.sub-arbitrary }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>
  {% endif %}</li>{% endfor %}
</ul>

<p>Hope that answers it</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces this:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>the example</title>
</head>

<body>

<h4>products:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Product One: Value
    <ul>
      <li>Associated Product: Associated Value</li>
      <li>Another associate: with its associated value</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Product Two: Value
    <ul>
      <li>nested product Two: Two's nested's associate value</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Product Three: Value</li>
  <li>Product Four: SomeValue</li>
</ul>

<p>Hope that answers it</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this originally but it only iterated over the first instance of "sub items". Any thoughts as to why that would be happening?

Comment: No idea. I do something similar in my pages and it works fine.

Comment: Take a look at my example. If that produces anything else, something is wrong with your setup.