# is possible to loop through yaml variables of jekyll page without knowing them?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I want to iterate with liquid through the list of the yaml variables of Jekyll page without knowing their names and print their key / value.

I illustrate my question with an "object" (wrong) formalism :

As :

```
{% assign variables = page.data %}
{% for var in variables %}
 key-name : {{var.key}} , value : {{var.value}} , 
{% endfor%}
```

And thus for a  post file with the simple yaml front matter :

```
---
layout: post
title: MyBlog
---
```

I want to get :

```
key-name : layout , value : post
key-name : title , value : MyBlog
```

To be precise, I don't want to loop inside one of the variable itself as  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761152/yaml-front-matter-for-jekyll-and-nested-lists) as I don't know the structure of the Yaml front matter of my jekyll posts  because they are each different.

Probably I'm wrong, but I don't find any clear liquid syntax which could do the job.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loop on a **`Page`** (Page objects like index, about, ...) variables, you receive arrays like :

```
{% for var in page %}
  {{ var | inspect }} => ["layout", "default"]
```

If you want to print key value pairs, you just have to call array elements by their indexes :

```
{% for var in page %}
  key-name : {{ var[0] }} , value : {{ var[1] }}
{% endfor%}
```

**Edit** : Which is not the same with **Collections**, where "*pages*" are in fact Document objects (**`posts`** or any custom collection)

Here you have to call key/value like this :

```
{% for var in page %}
      key : {{ var }} , value : {{ page[var] }}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: What is your jekyll version ?

Comment: jekyll 3.7.3 . You mean they change the syntax ?

Comment: Sorry, I finally get it. Page and Document objects are not behaving  the same way. Edited my answer.