# How to embed a d3.js example to the Jekyll blog post?

Tags: html, d3.js, jekyll

I am experimenting with this Jekyll theme 
http://richbray.me/frap/

And I want to create a blog post showing this D3.js example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502

So the main difficulty is how to let Markdown render the script to let d3.js show its contents.
Any ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754391/embed-javascript-in-markdown) may help.

Comment: So the solution provided is to add a empty new line after the opening tag. I will try and report, thanks.

Comment: After multiple tries, I don't think I could get a example set up correctly. I actually don't think you can embed a Javascript script in Markdown (.md) file and render and execute it to show what it is. Please prove I am wrong.

Comment: Fortunately, The answer by @nicksuch proved my statement upstairs is wrong. Hats off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few ways to get this to work:

#### Embed an `<iframe>`

In [the d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502), there's an embedded iframe:

> ```
> <iframe src="/mbostock/raw/4061502/0a200ddf998aa75dfdb1ff32e16b680a15e5cb01/" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
> ```

You can change this to

> ```
> <iframe src="http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4061502/0a200ddf998aa75dfdb1ff32e16b680a15e5cb01/" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
> ```

Then, you can simply paste this iframe line into your markdown file. Make sure that you have an empty line before and after it.

You can also add `width="600" height="400"` attributes to that iframe element so that most of the chart will fit in the iframe.

#### Target a block element within the document (e.g. `<div>` instead of `<body>`)

- change `var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")` to `var svg = d3.select("div#example").selectAll("svg")`
- save `morley.csv` (you can get it [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4061502/raw/7f2acaba70d05ce76b3e6f8085c194d32f8e83be/morley.csv)) to the root directory of your Jekyll site, then change `d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, csv)` to `d3.csv("/morley.csv", function(error, csv)` (copy this file into your Jekyll project to resolve cross-site scripting errors)
- change `<script src="box.js"></script>` to `<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4061502/0a200ddf998aa75dfdb1ff32e16b680a15e5cb01/box.js"></script>`
- create a new element called `<div id="example"></div>`

I created [this Jekyll blog post](http://www.nicksuch.com/2014/03/26/d3-sample/) that shows how to do this. Also, check out [Matt Shwery's blog post](http://mattshwery.com/d3-js) (and [raw markdown](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mshwery/mattshwery.com/master/_posts/articles/2013-04-6-d3-js.md)) with another d3 / Jekyll example.

Comment: Well, what more can I say. You rock! And this d3.select("div#example").selectAll("svg") is a true d3.js marvelous, I am still getting familiar with it, would like to know more. Also worth mentioning, I have changed to another Jekyll template and this example works great. I may not test on my original Jekyll template, so not sure if it works there.

Comment: am getting this error message after copy paste iframe `Refused to display 'http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4061502/0a200ddf998aa75dfdb1ff32e16b680a15e5cb01/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.ocks.org".`

Answer (score 4):

inframe is no longer supported by bl.ocks 
you will get the following error

Refused to display 'http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4061502/0a200ddf998aa75dfdb1ff32e16b680a15e5cb01/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.ocks.org".

you can try using rawgit.com