# Embed d3.js to a Jekyll Post

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, jekyll

Exactly as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651346/how-to-embed-a-d3-js-example-to-the-jekyll-blog-post), I want to embed this [particular example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366) on my blog.

I tried using `<iframe>` but `bl.ocks.org` isn't supporting it anymore. I tried with `<iframe>` using `rawgit` but this too didn't work. I tried using the method given [here](http://dkmehrmann.github.io/blog/2016/05/01/d3.html) and it works! but for my example it doesn't.

I have inspected both of these sites ([this one](http://www.nicksuch.com/2014/03/26/d3-sample/)) and ([this too](http://dkmehrmann.github.io/blog/2016/05/01/d3.html)), and found out that in my case the `d3 script` isn't appending any `svg` element in my custom `div`. ( Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22669498/4928430) for the method I used )

Please suggest me how to proceed with this.

Comment: Your question should be self contained and shouldn't rely on links to be complete. Links should be there only as sources and additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. creating another folder in `_includes` in the main `Jekyll`
   directory and placing my custom `.js` files in it.
2. Then change `d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")` to
   `d3.select("div#example").append("svg")`.

Finally it renders the custom `.js` files alright.